# jQuery DatePicker With Multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a jQuery date picker control that works fine for once instance, but I'm not sure how to get it to work for multiple instances.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#my_date').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Without the For Each loop, it works fine, but if there's more than one item in the "MyRecords" collection, then only the first text box gets a date picker (which makes sense since it's tied to the ID). I tried assigning a class to the text box and specifying:

```
$('.my_class').datepicker();
```

but while that shows a date picker everywhere, they all update the first text box.

What is the right way to make this work?

Comment: `but while that shows a date picker everywhere, they all update the first text box` You are doing something wrong because this shouldn't happen using class  See there: http://jsfiddle.net/jc0rwxbc/

Comment: Can we have your HTML code plz?

Comment: i tried my every possible solution but it happens

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample code in question itself to replicate your issue, otherwise, your question is useless

Comment: @Prog the datetime picker field is comming from ajax

Comment: @CyberSoul Remove any duplicate IDs...  Using duplicate IDs, this happen: http://jsfiddle.net/jc0rwxbc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<input type="text" name="txtdate1" class="my_date">
<input type="text" name="txtdate2" class="my_date">
<input type="text" name="txtdate3" class="my_date">

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('.my_date').datepicker();
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code and also your textbox IDs must be different, like as follows

```
<input id="my_id_1"  class="my_class" name="date_1" />

<input id="my_id_2"  class="my_class" name="date_2" />

<input id="my_id_3"  class="my_class" name="date_3" />
```

In the JavaScript

```
 $('.my_class').each(function(){
            $(this).datepicker();
    });
   $('.my_class').click(function(){
        $(this).focus();
   });
```

Comment: that shows a date picker everywhere, they all update the first text box.

Comment: That's correct, the IDs **must** be unique but still, no need of the each loop